# Has this variant on multiplication by a natural number been studied before?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-polynomials

Let $X$ denote an additively-denote commutative monoid. Then we get an action $\star$ of $\mathbb{N}$ on the powerset $\mathcal{P}(X)$ as follows: given a natural number $n$ and a set $A \subseteq X$, define $$n \star A = \left\{x \in X : \exists_{I \in \mathbf{FinSet}}\left(|I|=n \wedge \exists_{f:I \rightarrow A}\left(x = \sum_{i \in I} f(i) \right)\right)\right\}.$$

For example:

- $2 \star \{x\} = \{2x\}$
- $3 \star \{x\} = \{3x\}$
- $2 \star \{x,y\} = \{2x,x+y,2y\}$
- $3 \star \{x,y\} = \{3x,2x+y,x+2y,3y\}$
- $2 \star \{x,y,z\} = \{2x,2y,2z,x+y,x+z,y+z\}$

So it's basically a variant on multiplication by a natural number scalar in which the thing getting added to itself $n$ times is allowed to vary. Kind of reminds me of multichoose.

> **Question.** Has this variant on scalar multiplication studied before? If so, what is it called, and where can I learn more?

Comment: Dropping constants, this looks just like $x^n$, $(x+y)^n$, etc. (where on RHS addition is usual multiplication, commas are usual addition and coefficients are powers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$n \star A\,$ is called the ***n-fold iterated sumset*** on the wikipedia [sumset page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset) (which also includes more references):

> In additive combinatorics, the sumset (also called the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition)) of two subsets $A$ and $B$ of an abelian group $G$ (written additively) is defined to be the set of all sums of an element from $A$ with an element from $B$. That is,
>   $$\displaystyle A+B=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$$
>   The ***n-fold iterated sumset*** of $A$ is
>   $$\displaystyle nA=A+\cdots +A$$
>   where there are $n$ summands.

Comment: The fact that the $n$-fold sumset is abbreviated to just $nA$ in additive combinatorics (despite the potential confusion with dilation by a factor of $n$) underlines just how fundamental a concept it is in that field.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like some sort of convolution on sets. For any two sets $A, B \in P(X)$, define the product
$$ A \cdot B = \{a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$$
For example, we have that
$$ \{x, y\} \cdot \{x, y\} = \{2x, x + y, 2y\} $$
and in general, the star operator $n \star A$ is the $n$-fold product of $A$.

Note that if $e \in X$ is the monoid unit, then $(P(X), \cdot)$ is a monoid with unit $\{e\}$.